# Autocomplete doesn´t hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to create an autocomplete input text. 
The issue is that after deleting the input, the results are still shown:

This is the script:

```
function autocomplet() {

    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#especialidad_doctor').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'buscar_especialidad.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#especialidad_id').show();
                $('#especialidad_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#especialidad_id').hide();
    }
}
```

And this the HTML part:

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input_container">
                 <label for="inputEmail">¿Cuál es la especialidad que buscas? 
                 </label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="especialidad_doctor" autocomplete="off" name="especialidad_doctor"  onkeyup="autocomplet()" placeholder="Ejemplo: Pediatría" required>
                <ul id="especialidad_id"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: it should be `keyword.length > min_length` not `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `equal` sign. If your input has no character, it's length is `0`, So comparing with the `>= min_length`, it returns `true`. So the `else`, block will not work anymore

```
if (keyword.length > min_length) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Easyautocomplete it is powerful and easy to set up:

https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete